# Is it possible to compute $\int_1^{+ \infty} \frac{dx}{x^2(1+e^x)}$?

Tags: improper-integrals

Essentially, all is in the title: Is it possible to compute the integral $$\int_1^{+ \infty} \frac{dx}{x^2(1+e^x)} \hspace{1cm} ?$$

I suspected some relation with a [polygamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function), but I was not able to find something explicit.

Comment: It can be expressed as a sum of $Ei(1/n)$ terms where Ei is the [exponential integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html). Would you be satisfied with that?

Comment: @RagibZaman. Could you clarify for me ? Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The integrand can be written in this form (using a geometric series expansion): $$ \frac{1}{x^2 e^x (1+ e^{-x}) } = \frac{1}{x^2e^x} \left( 1 - e^{-x}+e^{-2x}-e^{-3x}+\cdots\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1} x^{-2} e^{-kx}.$$ 

It remains to calculate $\int^{\infty}_1 x^{-2} e^{-kx},$ which can be expressed in terms of nice constants and $\int^{\infty}_{1/k} x^{-1} e^{-x} dx = Ei(1/k).$

Comment: @RagibZaman. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substituting the series $\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n e^{-nx}$ and interchanging the order of summation and integration,
\begin{align}
\int_1^{+ \infty} \frac{dx}{x^2(1+e^x)} &= \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}\,dx}{x^2(1+e^{-x})}\\
&=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}e^{-x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n e^{-nx}\,dx\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}e^{-x} e^{-nx}\,dx\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2} e^{-(n+1)x}\,dx\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \left((n+1)\operatorname{Ei}(-(n+1))+e^{-(n+1)}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n e^{-(n+1)} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n (n+1)\operatorname{Ei}(-(n+1))\\
&=\frac{1}{1+e}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n (n+1)\operatorname{Ei}(-(n+1))\\
&=\frac{1}{1+e}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} n\operatorname{Ei}(-n).
\end{align}

Note: using, $u=(n+1)x$,

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2} e^{-(n+1)x}\,dx = \int_{n+1}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)}{u^2} e^{-u}\,du\\
=(n+1)\operatorname{Ei}(-(n+1))+e^{-(n+1)}$$