# how to integrate $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2(1+e^x)} $?

Tags: integration

how to integrate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2(1+e^x)}$? 
How can I integrate this difficult form of integration, I tried many times to solve it by parts or by substitution but I didn't get it.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2677552/a-difficult-improper-integral) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816678/is-it-possible-to-compute-int-1-infty-fracdxx21ex). There's no simple closed form.

Comment: Do you have any specific bounds? Are you trying to solve this with something else? Given more context, this question might be reasonable to answer, but as is, the only answer is you can't, as far as closed forms are concerned.

Comment: the bounds are from negative infinity to infinity

Comment: If the bounds are from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, I think you better edit your question.

Comment: Please correct it. I don't know how to write the boundaries.

Comment: I'm glad to see someone added the integral's limits for you, after you said you didn't know how. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a guide.

Answer (score 2):

Using $\int_{\Bbb R}f(x)dx=\int_0^\infty[f(x)+f(-x)]dx$,$$\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{1}{1+e^x}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^2}\underbrace{\left[\frac{1}{1+e^x}+\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}\right]}_1dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2}=\infty.$$

Comment: I don't understand this step $\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^2}\underbrace{\left[\frac{1}{1+e^x}+\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}\right]}_1dx$

Comment: @Mario $\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}=\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}=1-\frac{1}{1+e^x}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let u = -x => Integral from -infinity to infinity of du/(u^2*(1+e-u)) = integral of e^u/(u^2(1+e^u)) du.

Take the original integral and add it to this one to get(switch u to x):
2I = integral (e^x+1)/x^2 *1/(e^x+1) du=integral of 1/x^2 dx.

Integral from -infinity to infinity of 1/x^2 dx = 2*int from 0 to infinity of 1/x^2 dx = -1/x from 0 to infinity which diverges.

So the original integral equals divergent/2 which still diverges.

Comment: Please [reformat](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).